# Remove labels from top

Tags: qgis, labeling

Is it possible to send labels beyond a polygon feature in QGIS?

I have some polygons with transparency and want the labels to go beyond the polygons. For now all the labels appear on top.

Comment: This might help you (https://youtu.be/I0hFiiA31cg). Basically you need to be on Edit mode and then select advanced labeling.

Comment: This is how it worked in older versions (nowadays it's easier) and just shows how to move labels, but does not help with the problem of OP.

Answer (score 4):

In the `Labels` section, under `Placement`, one can specify that features can act as obstacles for labels.
Optionally, under `Settings...` it is possible to assign a "Weight" to features (think of that as a rendering priority).

[image]